# Is it possible to scale Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

If I write an entire web app in GAS and then it gets popular and it starts receiving a thousand requests per second. Is there any way to either pay Google to handle it, or host my GAS app on non-Google infrastructure, in the same way that   [here](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki) does for Google App Engine?

Answer (score 0):

Your GAS script scales up automatically. The only thing that you should be worried about is your code where, if you have locks, thousands of users waiting for a lock will cause delays to the user. Other than that, scaling up shouldn't be a problem. After all, there are possibly millions of scripts being run by different users.

Comment: There are of course quotas for many api calls, but it looks like on https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard there are no quotas for bytes served or concurrent users or bandwidth. But if it is "unlimited", I wonder what the real world limits are, like at what point do users start seeing bad performance?

Comment: Yes, as you pointed out, there are limits on the API calls. But I'd imagine whatever traffic you can think of for your script will be miniscule compared to what Google can serve. So, I don't think users will see bad performance in terms of delivering the UI etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen Google suggest Apps Script is the tool for that kind of scale.  Go to App Engine, do not pass Go, etc.

There is no third-party implementation of the Google Apps Script services.  It is, however, a JavaScript implementation on Java (think [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino)) which you can run yourself - or you could run on App Engine and use the Java GData APIs to replace the Apps Script services.

Answer (score 0):

if the App is running under the user account (execute the app as the user accessing the web app) it will consume each user's quotas and use their own account resources (docs, sheets, etc). This would allow for 'unlimited' scalability.

This is just my own view, am I right or totally wrong?